# Cómo popular un diccionario con datos que vienen de SQLite (lambda expressions)?

Tags: c#, diccionarios, lambda

Tengo este código:

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, StrainGroupings>();

                var t = Connection.Table<StrainGroupings>()
                    .Where(sg => sg.Locale == locale)
                    .Join(Connection.Table<OperationStrainGroups>(), 
                        strainGrouping => strainGrouping.StrainGroupName, 
                        operationStrainGroup => operationStrainGroup.StrainGroupName, 
                        (strainGrouping, operationStrainGroup) => new { Name = operationStrainGroup.OperationName, sg = strainGrouping });
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que Tkey que es string sea Name, y TValue sea sg,

Esto es lo que he intentado:
`t.Select(r => result.Add(r.Name, r.sg));` pero no me funciona:

> The arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments explicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al menos, esto me funciona:

```
result = t.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(row => row.Name.ToString(), row => row.sg);
```

y combinándolo obtengo el siguiente código que funciona pero seguro que puede mejorarse:

```
result = Connection.Table<StrainGroupings>()
            .Where(sg => sg.Locale == locale)
            .Join(Connection.Table<OperationStrainGroups>(), 
                strainGrouping => strainGrouping.StrainGroupName, 
                operationStrainGroup => operationStrainGroup.StrainGroupName, 
                (strainGrouping, operationStrainGroup) => new { Name = operationStrainGroup.OperationName, sg = strainGrouping })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ToDictionary(row => row.Name.ToString(), row => row.sg);
```